# Web Server "Content-Type" not configuring correctly on Apache

Tags: apache, webserver, mime-types, webassembly, gzipstream

Extremely new to web servers:

I'm trying to configure my web server to serve WebAssemblies (Edit: .wasm) as aplication/wasm
I'm on a Hostinger host which uses an Apache as I understand.  I'm also using gzip

(Edit #3 The webpage is a Unity 'WebGL' build and the WebAssemblies are being streamed)

My webpage is on a subdomain and this is my directory structure on the server:
[image]

(Edit #2)

This is my public_html .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

(End Edit #2)

And this is my .htaccess file in the Build folder:

```
# This configuration file should be uploaded to the server as "<Application Folder>/Build/.htaccess"
# This configuration has been tested with Unity 2020.1 builds, hosted on Apache/2.4
# NOTE: "mod_mime" Apache module must be enabled for this configuration to work.

# The following lines are required for builds without decompression fallback, compressed with gzip


<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding gzip .unityweb
    AddEncoding gzip .wasm
    AddType application/wasm .wasm
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .gz
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    AddType application/octet-stream .data.gz
    AddType application/wasm .wasm.gz
    AddType application/javascript .js.gz
    AddType application/octet-stream .symbols.json.gz
</IfModule>
```

According to the console error it seems my 'Build/WebGL Build.wasm.gz' file doesn't have the right MIME type:
[image]

And according to the Network tab it has a MIME type of text/plain:
[image]

So of course the question is why is 'Build/WebGL Build.wasm.gz' not being served with the application/wasm MIME-type?

Comment: Is `mod_mime` enabled on your server?  Can you remove the `IfModule` lines and see if it works without those?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, if I remove the IfModule lines it no longer works...

Comment: I forgot to add my second .htaccess.  I added it to the question just now...

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean?  Do you get a 500 error?   Is there information in there error_log when that happens?

Comment: 2 errors:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token & WebGL Build.loader.js:1 Unable to parse Build/WebGL Build.framework.js.gz! This can happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: gzip" present. Check browser Console and Devtools Network tab to debug.

Comment: What is the invalid or unexpected token?   (did you remember to remove the `</IfModule>` too?)

Comment: I did remove </IfModule> also. What I put in the comment is everything that showed in that console error.  When I click the file link it shows gibberish.  I assume because it's showing the gzip file without decompressing it as indicated by the second error in the comment.

Comment: Part of the build/.htaccess is to handle gzip extension and the other is to handle WebAssembly Streaming...

Comment: No errors from your server then like in the error log file?

Comment: The only error log file I can find, 'error_log', is in the public_html directory which I take to be my root dir:

Comment: [12-Feb-2021 00:07:11 UTC] WordPress database error Multiple primary key defined for query ALTER TABLE `wp_mec_occurrences` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `post_id` (`post_id`), ADD KEY `occurrence` (`occurrence`); made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, MEC_feature_update->update, MEC_feature_update->version5100, MEC_db->q
[18-Oct-2021 22:36:17 UTC] Astra: db version updated successfully!

Comment: Last comment is the contents of 'error_log' of course (Wouldn't fit in a comment...)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem related to your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems my first answer had a flaw even if it still worked. This is unacceptable as it leaves the door WIDE open for yet undiscovered problems and new problems related to updates to Unity and WebXR Exporter.

It was pointed out to me that some files still have the wrong type (i.e. 'WebGL Framework.js.gz' should be type JavaScript but actually has type wasm.)

So, it turns out there was a at least a couple of problems here:

#1 Spaces are required between extensions. So for instance, if you use:

```
'AddType application/javascript .data.gz'
```

the command is ignored (I assume because it's a syntax error.)  However if you use:

```
'AddType application/javascript .data .gz'
```

it will work.

#2 The second problem seems to be old Unity documentation.  The '.htaccess' in the documentaion does not seem to work anymore.

**My gracious thanks goes to m2 from the WebXR Discord server!  m2 has provided me the .htaccess file that seems to work perfectly!**

```
# This configuration file should be uploaded to the server as "<Application Folder>/Build/.htaccess"
# This configuration has been tested with Unity 2020.1 builds, hosted on Apache/2.4
# NOTE: "mod_mime" Apache module must be enabled for this configuration to work.

# The following lines are required for builds without decompression fallback, compressed with gzip


<IfModule mod_mime.c>

<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.data.gz$">
  Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
  Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.js.gz$">
  Header set Content-Type "application/javascript"
  Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.wasm.gz$">
  Header set Content-Type "application/wasm"
  Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.gz$">
  Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.wasm$">
  # Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
  Header set Content-Type "application/wasm"
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

(*** Edit #2 ***)

I found out my server is actually a LightSpeed Web 6.0.9 Enterprise which is an "Apache alternative" not sure if this is relevant...

(*** End Edit #2 ***)

Now all the files have their proper type as indicated by the Network panel:

[image]

Evidence that WebAssembly streaming is now working is that there are no longer wasm errors and the page loads TWICE as fast.

I am EXTREMELY new to servers so if anyone can confirm my analysis I would GREATLY appreciate it!!!

Comment: This updated .htaccess solved the issue for me. Thanks for sharing

Comment: About you Edit #2 question, LiteSpeed works similar (Harder, Better, Faster, Stronger (pun intented)) to Apache , so it's irrelevant :)